# Maven to include JAR that is generated by that build

Tags: maven

Normally we use *dependency* tag in pom.xml to have Maven include a JAR on the classpath and it also packages that dependency.

What if the JAR is generated in a step of the same project's build? I mean, it's not the compile plugin that generates it, it is a JAR without any java source and an external executable creates it.

I can use maven exec plugin to have my JAR generated and maven install plugin to have it installed to my local repository. But still I can't have it as a dependency in the same project: No matter which phase I put my JAR generator command in, the dependency check will happen before that and fail because the JAR does not yet exist.

Is system scope dependency my best choice? Then I need to give up packaging. And it's deprecated. And the JAR needs to be outside the project directory.

Or the JAR generator must be in a separate pom? Also not very nice because the JAR is only used by this one project.

Can I configure the dependency plugin to defer the dependency check and download to compile phase?

Any other solution?

This pom almost works, but first time I need to install the generated thing manually to the repo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>something-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>something</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>something-sample</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <jnbridge.path>C:/Program Files (x86)/JNBridge/JNBridgePro v9.0</jnbridge.path>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-proxies-jar</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>jnbproxy.bat</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>jnbridge.local</groupId>
                            <artifactId>proxies</artifactId>
                            <version>0.0.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${basedir}/proxies.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--
        Yes, these are true system-scope dependencies. JNBridge is expected to be
        installed on the system wherever this project is built.
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jnbridge.org.apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${jnbridge.path}/jnbcore/bcel-5.1-jnbridge.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jnbridge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnbcore</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${jnbridge.path}/jnbcore/jnbcore.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        This one will be installed to local maven repo in the process-test-resources phase,
        as defined in the project/build/plugins section of this file.
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jnbridge.local</groupId>
            <artifactId>proxies</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- other dependencies... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Use a repository manager upload that jar there and use it a usual dependency. Using system scope is strongly discouraged it's deprecated a long time...

Comment: Would that fix anything @khmarbaise?

Comment: Okay, I'll clarify. The point is, the JAR must be as fresh as the build itself. Must be generated from the files of the same Git repository as the Java sources, the same commit as the compilation source; the whole thing is part of the code, just not compiling with the java compiler but using an exe. Installing manually is no go, no matter if it's installing to a local repository or a repository manager.